# setuptools.setup can't find dylib library files but they are there

Tags: python, macos, setuptools, setup.py, dylib

When I run my `setup.py` file, I get several warnings of the following form:
`warning: no files found matching 'myfile.dylib`.

```
In [1]: ls -la /path/to/myfile.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 kilojoules  admin     55680 Jun 11 13:34 /path/to/myfile.dylib
```

I am running the setup function with an extension which I made using the setuptools.extension.Extension function, specifying the include dirs and library dirs as a list which I have confirmed includes the files `setup.py` can't find.

```
In [2]: include_dirs
Out[2]: 
['some/path/somewhere'
 '/usr/local/path/to',
 'other/paths']

In [3]: library_dirs
Out[3]: 
['some/path/somewhere'
 '/path/to',
 'other/paths']
```

I'm not sure where this process is failing, and why python can't find the include libraries. Is it because these are `.dylib` files? I'm on OSX, in case that's relevant information. What could possibly be causing this mysterious error?

```python
My_ext = Extension(name='My_ext',
                     sources=sources,
                     include_dirs=include_dirs,
                     define_macros=define_macros,
                     extra_compile_args=CXX_FLAGS,
                     extra_link_args=LD_FLAGS,
                     library_dirs=library_dirs,
                     libraries=libraries,
                     language='c++')
setup(name='My_ext',
      version=my_version_number,
      description='a dummy extension',
      py_modules=['module1', 'module2']
      ext_modules=[My_ext],
      zip_safe=False,
      data_files=data_files)
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually `include_dirs` are the locations for header includes called from your code, whilst `library_dirs` are the locations for linked libs in addition to dynamically linked libraries `.dylib`

Try changing `library_dirs` to the lcoation of `myfile.dylib`.

Comment: `Library_dirs` also contains the path to `myfile.dylib`. I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Try `libraries` also.